# Creating different lenght tables for pdf reports

Tags: php, laravel, logic

I am currently working on creating reports for our system. I am coding, and it is working as expected. The reason why I am asking for feedback is to improve my code because, in the future, I will need to create more systems like this. Basically, I am passing data to a helper function with start points and end points. It also calculates the end points based on the category. When the category is encountered in the loop, it adds one number to the end of the loop to ensure that no more rows are printed than expected.

Getting data from db and sorting to get the filtered array

```
        $dataCollection = collect($data);

        $sortedData = $dataCollection->sortBy('cate_id'); 

        $higherValueData = [];
        $lowerValueData = [];
        $totalValues = [];

        foreach ($sortedData as $item) {
            $codeValue = preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#', '', $item->code_value);

            $newItem = [
                'name' => $item->name,
                'ar_name' => $item->ar_name,
                'code_value' => $item->code_value,
                'code' => $item->code,
                'cate_id' => $item->cate_id,
                'cat_name' => $item->cat_name,
            ];

            if ($codeValue > 0.35) {
                $higherValueData[] = $newItem;
            } else {
                $lowerValueData[] = $newItem;
            }
            $totalValues[] = $newItem;
        }

        $noneReactiveCount = count(array_filter($totalValues, function ($item) {
            return preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#', '', $item['code_value']) <= 0.35;
        }),);

        $lowCount = count(array_filter($totalValues, function ($item) {
            return preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#', '', $item['code_value']) > 0.35 && preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#', '', $item['code_value']) <= 3.49;
        }),);

        $mediumCount = count(array_filter($totalValues, function ($item) {
            return  preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#', '', $item['code_value']) >= 3.5 && preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#', '', $item['code_value']) <= 49.99;
        }),);

        $highCount = count( array_filter($totalValues, function ($item) {
                return preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#', '',$item['code_value']) >= 50.0;
            }),);

        $data = [
                'lowCount' => $lowCount,
                'highCount' => $highCount,
                'foodSense' => $foodSense, 
                'reportData' => $sortedData, 
                'mediumCount' => $mediumCount,
                'lowerValueData' => $lowerValueData,
                'higherValueData' => $higherValueData, 
                'noneReactiveCount' => $noneReactiveCount,
                'totalValues'=>$totalValues
            ];
```

Passing it to helper function to return the HTML need for displaying the table in the page

```
if (!function_exists('display_table')) {
    function display_table($start, $end, $tableValue, $number)
    {
        $category = null;
        $cateCount = 0;
        $htmlTable =' <table class="sensitivity-data-table"><tbody>';

        for ($i = $start; $i < $end;) {
            if ($i >= count($tableValue) || $start >= $end || $i + $cateCount >= $end) {
                $end = $end - $cateCount;
                break; 
            }

            $htmlTable .= '<tr>';
            if ($category != $tableValue[$i]['cate_id']) {
                $htmlTable .= '<th class="th-lg" colspan="2">' . $tableValue[$i]['cat_name'] . '</th>';
                $htmlTable .= '<th class="th-sm sensitivity-tab">Sensitivity</th>';
                $htmlTable .= '</tr>';
                $category = $tableValue[$i]['cate_id'];
                $cateCount ++;
            } else {
                $htmlTable .= '<td class="td-lg" colspan="2">';
                $htmlTable .= $number . ': ' . $tableValue[$i]['name'] . '-' . $tableValue[$i]['ar_name'] . '<span>' .
                    $tableValue[$i]['code_value'] . '</span>';
                $htmlTable .= '</td>';
                $htmlTable .= '<td class="td-sm"><span class="sensitivity-circle ' . getColor($tableValue[$i]['code_value']) . '"></span></td></tr>';
                $number++;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        
        $htmlTable .= ' </tbody></table>';
        return ['end' => $end, 'htmlTable' => $htmlTable, 'start' => $number];
    }
}
```

Calling helper function with data start point then added the end point which is calculated dynamically and response of the returned function

```
              $hightStart = 0; 
              $highEnd = $hightStart + 20;
              $response = display_table($hightStart,$highEnd,$higherValueData, $number); 
              $hightStart = $response['end'];
              $number = $response['start'];
              echo $response['htmlTable'];
```

This is working as expected

Comment: Hi, just an advice when posting many pieces of code, comments on the code help readability and linkage.

Comment: We don't do code reviews on working code here, we spot issues and help with programming problems. There is a Code Review stackexchange site you can try, but please read their guidance carefully before posting, as you will likely need to be more specific about the kind of feedback you are seeking.